# Download all sheets to PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found the code below which does exactly what I want but only for a particular sheet. I want to download all the active sheets.

```
function PDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetId = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1").getSheetId(); 
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export?exportFormat=pdf&gid=" + sheetId + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var str = '<input type="button" value="Download" onClick="location.href=\'' + url + '\'" >';
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(str);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Click the button to download");
}
```

Any helpt would be great!

Comment: What do you mean by all active sheets? Only one sheet at a time can be active (the one that is currently open).

Comment: Apologies, I mean all the sheets that are not hidden. So I would like the same result as if I would export the workbook through the menu.

Answer (score 1):

- Use [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) to retrieve all sheets of a spreadsheet
- Use [isSheetHidden()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#issheethidden) to determine either a sheet is hidden or not
- For all sheets that are not hidden, run the same request as in your intial code - iterating with a loop, e.g. [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

### Sample

```js
function PDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  allSheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    if(!sheet.isSheetHidden()){
      var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId(); 
      var url = "https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export?exportFormat=pdf&gid=" + sheetId + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
      var str = '<input type="button" value="Download" onClick="location.href=\'' + url + '\'" >';
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(str);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Click the button to download");
    }
  })
}
```